# How to print (*) vertically and horizontally using c# with console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

```
I'm doing odd and even number to print (*) using console application
For ex:
If i'm entering the odd number as 5 then the output should be like:
  *
*****
  *
  *
  *
```

### My C# code are:

```
namespace csharpstar
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number:");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("The number is Evennumber");
            Console.Read();
        }
        else
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                    Console.Write("*");
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have managed to bring the output as horizontally but no idea about vertical so

Answer (score 0):

To print `num` vertically, you would do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    Console.WriteLine("*");
    //Console.Write("*\n"); will also work
}
```

This will output `*` on a new line every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to use PadLeft.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process();
    }

    static void Process()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int num);
        Print(num);
    }

    static void Print(int num)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty.PadLeft(num, '*'));
        }
        else
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*");
            }

        }

        Process();
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process();
    }

    static void Process()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int num);
        Print(num);
    }

    static void Print(int num)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty.PadLeft(num, '*'));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  *  ");
            }
        }

        Process();
    }
}
```

And so:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process();
    }

    static void Process()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int num);
        Print(num);
    }

    static void Print(int num)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if ((i % 2 == 0) && i == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty.PadLeft(num, '*'));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  *  ");
            }
        }

        Process();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur kind reply Jonathan and i'm getting result but If i am entering the number 5 as odd number then the output of (*) should be vertically and horizontally so is that possible?

Comment: I do not get it right if the number is 5 then all the odd ones should be printed vertically and all pairs horizontally is this?

It should be printed like this:
  *
*****
  *
*****
  *

Or like this:
  *
*****
  *
  *
  *

Comment: See if any of the above suggestion meets you, grateful to help you.